# Centre a 4 Horizontally DIV Block Using CSS

Tags: html, block, center

I have four div blocks and I want to Centre the Horizontally, they keep stacking under each other.. any ideas how I can do this.

```
<div class="container">
   <div style="width:78%; margin:0 auto;">
    <div class="block">1. name of the company</div>
    <div class="block">2. name of the company</div>
    <div class="block">3. name of the company</div>
    <div class="block">4. name of the company</div>
</div>
```

Comment: err it does this? - http://jsfiddle.net/KCsS7/

Comment: i am not getting ! what you want.

Comment: What are the attributes for `.block` and `.container` ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand is that you want the `blocks` next to each other.

Is this what you are looking for? [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pXcD6/1/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block-wrapper">
        <div class="block">1. name of the company</div>
        <div class="block">2. name of the company</div>
        <div class="block">3. name of the company</div>
        <div class="block">4. name of the company</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.block-wrapper {
    width: 78%;
    text-align: center;
}
.block {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using inline-block.

http://jsfiddle.net/8Qk5K/

```
display: inline-block;
```

This type of display value makes each block take up as much horizontal space as it needs (or it is given to) . Works best with percentage values if you want it responsive.

Also, I recommend using  http://jsfiddle.net for demos. It is much easier for everybody to understand!

Good luck!